# Expand/ Collapse UiTableViewCell if category has item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need help expanding/ collapsing my cell when its filled. My previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762004/multi-level-categories-with-items-on-all-levels-in-uitableview) explains what i was trying to achieve and answered my question but i just dont know how to expand the cell in this setup. I've looked at code examples but they are just too complicated for my needs. If somebody could just send me in the right direction.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

NSString *key = [[self.tableObjects allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *sectionobjects = (NSArray*)[self.tableObjects objectForKey:key];

id object = [sectionobjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//They selected a product
if ([object isKindOfClass:[ProductObject class]]) {

    ProductObject *product = (ProductObject*)object;

    NSLog(@"%@", product.productTitle);
    NSLog(@"%@", product.productCode);
    NSLog(@"%@", product.productId);
}


//They selected a Category
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[CategoryObject class]]) {

    //Check to see if the CategoryObject has any ProductObjects associated with it
    if ([(CategoryObject*)object products]) {

        //Now you will need to pass array of ProductObjects this along to your next view controller.
        NSArray *cateogryProducts = [(CategoryObject*)object products];

        //For demonstration purposes, i'll run through and print out all the Products for this Category
        [cateogryProducts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(ProductObject *product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"%@", product.productTitle);
            NSLog(@"%@", product.productCode);
            NSLog(@"%@", product.productId);
        }];
    }

}
```

@random thanks for your input so far.

My previous post to view all my code: [Multi level categories with items on all levels in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762004/multi-level-categories-with-items-on-all-levels-in-uitableview)

**I want to achieve:** To show (expand / collapse) the item ( product) that sits in the first level cell ( category ) once clicked. Then to be able to click on the new cell ( product ) and open a new view controller

Added a image of what im trying to do.[image]

Comment: What is your question? How to change the height of cells?

Comment: To show the item ( product) that sits in the first level cell ( category ) once clicked. Then to be able to click on the new cell ( product ) and open a new view controller